# Java Multi-protocol design structure

Tags: java, oop, syntax, compilation

I've been looking through a lot of java projects for multiplayer games, and some of them use multi-protocol designs even though it's clear that only one protocol will ever be used.

For example:

```
package com.project.protocol.bg.impl

public class RedBackGroundColor extends BGColorProtocolType {

@Override
public int RBGColorHash() {
    return 123;
}

@Override
public String name() {
    return "default-red";
}

}
```

Even though red bg is the only color ever used in a completely FINISHED project.

Is it more professional to program a design like this?

Why do some people do it KNOWING full-well that they will only ever use one protocol.

Edit: Also consider that it was never intended that anybody whom bought the project would ever need to or want to add more protocols

Comment: What if you want to add more? It's safer in a world of changing expectations to design with the presumption that you may have to add something in, instead of presuming that it won't happen and then have to rewrite large portions of the code to make it work.

Comment: @ifly6 Edited op to take that into account. But what about fixed 'protocol' modules like "MaleCharacterProtocol" and "FemaleCharacterProtocol" Where you never need to add more, so why bother with a modular design?

Comment: Ever heard the saying "Never assume because it makes an..." well the same can be said for code that is not flexible. And i hope `MaleCharacterProtocol` and `FemaleCharacterProtocol` share some common parent class...

Comment: At that point, why have classes? Can't we store everything in bytes?

Comment: I generally agree with @ifly6 and RAZ_Muh_Taz, but would like to add that "something can change in the future" never should be the _only_ argument for abstraction (hello, over-abstraction). The concept shown realizes _loose coupling_ and allows to "program to an interface", rather than to the implementation. Loose coupling implies not only extensibility, but also reusability and maintainability.

Comment: I am not a fan of this practice myself. Not because of YAGNI, but rather because I do not like forced inheritance like this. In true OO, you design upwards, towards generalisation, instead of downwards, towards inheritance. Therefore, you should not need derivation until your design reveals classes of the same type (is-a) that need to be generalised.